# Is a stud a piercing?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

When you pierce your ears, nose, lip or belly button, is the jewelry you wear called a piercing? Is "Take off or put on your piercing" right?

I've seen "She has a nose piercing." Is the piercing the jewelry or the hole?

Is there a different between ear piercings and earrings?

Comment: The hole is a piercing, and the stud or other jewellery can be called a piercing too. An earring is just one kind of ear piercing.

Comment: I say only the hole is a piercing.  I would never look at an earring, nose ring, belly button ring, etc. outside of a person and call it "a piercing".

Comment: @stangdon - I might have been inclined to agree, had I not seen (e.g.) Merriam-Webster's entry for 'piercing' 1. adjective (penetrating, shrill, incisive etc) 2. noun 'a piece of jewelry (such as a ring or stud) that is attached to pierced flesh'. Also anecdotal stuff like 'Is it safe to buy piercings on Amazon?' and 'Piercing Mania', a UK website offers  items headed 'Piercings by type', one example of which is a 'dermal piercing': 'Dermal piercings are slightly different to your average body modification, in the sense that they are actually piercings that are anchored beneath the skin.'

Comment: @stangdon - some sites e.g. Amazon clarify that the items are 'piercing jewellery/jewelry'. I note also that Cambridge, for the noun, gives only the 'hole in the body' and 'the process of making such a hole' meanings.

Answer (score 1):

As has been suggested in the comments these adornments are called piercings. To avoid ambiguity you might want to refer to piercing jewellery if it might be confused with the hole made in the body part to receive the piercing. At least in the UK earrings would usually be referred to as pierced earrings only if it was necessary to distinguish them from clip-on earrings